# Efficiently track changes to a List<T>

Tags: c#

The following code fulfills some requirements that are not obvious from the title.  First of all, we want to avoid memory allocations, that is why it operates on preexisting lists.  Secondly, we don't need to track the items that are unchanged between the two instances of the list.  Thirdly, it is not meant to be used by multiple threads concurrently.  Fourthly, it uses List based on an upstream requirement.

It's purpose is to help, for instance, with discerning which download requests in a list that changes in the course of a batch operation need to be made because they haven't been and which need to be cancelled because they are no longer of concern.

```
/// <summary>
/// Meant to statefully compare a set of items to it's own changing self over time.  
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type contained in the List who's hashcode is used to determine the set difference.</typeparam>
public class SetDifferentiator<T> 
{
    private HashSet<T>[] swapHashes { get; set; } = new HashSet<T>[] {
        null /* init'd on first call to GetDifference */,
        new HashSet<T>()
    };

    private int currIdx = -1;
    private int prevIdx = -1;
    private HashSet<T> currhash;
    private HashSet<T> prevhash;
    private T item = default(T);

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the passed in lists to isolate the differences, putting the items that are new from this call
    /// to the previous in the <paramref name="novel"/> list, putting the items that are not in this call
    /// but were in the previous call in the <paramref name="disjoint"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The current state of the list which this class is statefully tracking the difference of</param>
    /// <param name="novel">List to put in the items that first appeared in the list on this call</param>
    /// <param name="disjoint">List to put in the items that appeared in the previous call but not in this one</param>
    public void GetDifference(List<T> current, List<T> novel, List<T> disjoint)
    {
        // This thing makes only this attempt to be thread safe - anything else
        // would be complicated and would involve accepting compromises, eg to perf
        lock (this)
        {
            novel.Clear();
            disjoint.Clear(); /* Not nec. 1st call, intrinsically, but now all are legit */

            if (currIdx == -1)
            {
                // First call to the method - set up the initial state
                currIdx = 0;
                prevIdx = 1; // for brevity

                currhash = new HashSet<T>(current);
                swapHashes[currIdx] = currhash;
                for (var i = 0; i < currhash.Count; i++)
                {
                    novel.Add(current[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Not first call - reinit state
                prevIdx = currIdx;
                currIdx = prevIdx == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                currhash = swapHashes[currIdx];
                prevhash = swapHashes[prevIdx];

                // Compare current to previous and collect state in method parameters
                for (int i = 0; i < current.Count; i++)
                {
                    item = current[i];

                    if (prevhash.Contains(item) == false && currhash.Contains(item) == false /* Only if currhash doesn't contain so as to avoid duplicates */)
                    {
                        // Current contains something previous didn't - we have sth novel
                        novel.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Previous shares sth with current - remove it from the prevhash 
                        // so as to end up with disjoint
                        prevhash.Remove(item);
                    }

                    // Set state for next call to this func because what is now currIdx 
                    // will have flipped to prevIdx by this point at that time
                    currhash.Add(item);
                }

                // What remains of previous is what is not in current - thus disjoint
                foreach (var old in prevhash) // foreach through hashsets is best perf-wise
                {
                    disjoint.Add(old);
                }

                prevhash.Clear();
                item = default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Context was asked for, so here it is provided.  Also, in doing so I realized some absurdities in the code that had snuck in during refactors, so thank you, now it is actually correct.

The following test provides output like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Size: 206        Edit/New/Remove: (16/28/22)
SET/LINQ: 392/595
Size: 207        Edit/New/Remove: (18/24/23)
SET/LINQ: 277/435
Size: 207        Edit/New/Remove: (2/2/2)
SET/LINQ: 266/399
Size: 203        Edit/New/Remove: (12/13/17)
SET/LINQ: 148/222
Size: 194        Edit/New/Remove: (23/13/22)
SET/LINQ: 135/216
Size: 195        Edit/New/Remove: (39/28/27)
SET/LINQ: 136/244
Size: 195        Edit/New/Remove: (1/2/2)
SET/LINQ: 133/241
Size: 191        Edit/New/Remove: (21/26/30)
SET/LINQ: 127/197
Size: 195        Edit/New/Remove: (22/29/25)
SET/LINQ: 124/264
Size: 195        Edit/New/Remove: (3/2/2)
SET/LINQ: 162/242
Size: 190        Edit/New/Remove: (29/28/33)
SET/LINQ: 118/208
Size: 184        Edit/New/Remove: (20/13/19)
SET/LINQ: 127/196
Size: 175        Edit/New/Remove: (42/20/29)
SET/LINQ: 117/192
Size: 169        Edit/New/Remove: (26/21/27)
SET/LINQ: 109/199
Size: 167        Edit/New/Remove: (10/16/18)
SET/LINQ: 156/177
Size: 169        Edit/New/Remove: (22/27/25)
SET/LINQ: 106/181
Size: 171        Edit/New/Remove: (6/5/3)
SET/LINQ: 142/166
Size: 171        Edit/New/Remove: (2/2/2)
SET/LINQ: 134/187
Size: 171        Edit/New/Remove: (11/13/13)
SET/LINQ: 107/170
Size: 175        Edit/New/Remove: (16/15/11)
SET/LINQ: 147/330
Totals SetDifferentiator/LINQ.Except()x2: 3163/5061
```

program.cs::main()

```
        var test = new SetDiffentiatorTest();
        test.TestSetDifferentiation(20);
```

SetDifferentiatorTest.cs

```
public class SetDiffentiatorTest
{
    public void TestSetDifferentiation(int times)
    {
        var strings = GetLongListOfStrings(times * 10);//.Distinct().ToList();
        var original = strings.ToList();
        var set = new SetDifferentiator<string>();
        var novel = new HashSet<string>();
        var disjoint = new HashSet<string>();
        var setnovel = new List<string>();
        var setdisjoint = new List<string>();
        List<string> linqnovel;
        List<string> linqdisjoint;

        // First call to the set differentiator setting up the initial state - all items are "novel"
        set.GetDifference(strings, setnovel, setdisjoint);

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");

        // This code modifies a list "times" number of times and causes differences to be calculated in a two different ways
        var totalTimeSpent_Set_Ticks = 0L;
        var totalTimeSpent_LINQ_Ticks = 0L;
        var rnd = new Random();
        var errors = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            // For our own comparisons
            var loopOriginal = strings.ToList();
            var loopOps = new List<string>();

            var edited = new HashSet<int>();
            var numToEdit = rnd.Next(1, Math.Min(strings.Count / 2 + 1, strings.Count));
            for (int j = 0; j < numToEdit; j++)
            {

                // Edit an item in the collection
                // Get a random index that we haven't edited this time around
                var idx = 0;
                do
                {
                    idx = rnd.Next(0, strings.Count);
                } while (edited.Contains(idx));
                edited.Add(idx);

                var x = rnd.Next(0, 3);
                if (x == 0 && strings.Count > 1)
                {
                    // remove an item
                    var removed = strings[idx];
                    strings.RemoveAt(idx);

                    loopOps.Add("Remove item " + removed);
                }
                else if (x == 1)
                {
                    // add an item
                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    strings.Add(guid);
                    novel.Add(guid);

                    loopOps.Add("Add item " + guid);
                }
                else
                {
                    // edit an item
                    var str = strings[idx];

                    // do modification that can be deconstructed at the end to see history
                    strings[idx] = str + " |";

                    loopOps.Add("Transform item " + str + " to " + strings[idx]);
                }
            }

            // Here we use the SetDifferentiator to calculate the difference
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            set.GetDifference(strings, setnovel, setdisjoint);
            watch.Stop();
            var SET_round_ticks = watch.ElapsedTicks;
            totalTimeSpent_Set_Ticks += watch.ElapsedTicks;
            watch.Reset();

            // Here we use pure LINQ to calculate the difference
            watch.Start();
            linqnovel = strings.Except(loopOriginal).ToList();
            linqdisjoint = loopOriginal.Except(strings).ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            var LINQ_round_ticks = watch.ElapsedTicks;
            totalTimeSpent_LINQ_Ticks += watch.ElapsedTicks;

            // Now we check for errors
            var loopErrors = new List<string>();
            var dif0a = linqnovel.Except(setnovel).ToList();
            var dif0b = setnovel.Except(linqnovel).ToList();
            if (dif0a.Count > 0 || dif0b.Count > 0)
            {
                loopErrors.Add($"SetDifference.Disjoint !Sequence= LINQ");
            }
            var dif0c = linqdisjoint.Except(setdisjoint).ToList();
            var dif0d = setdisjoint.Except(linqdisjoint).ToList();
            if (dif0c.Count > 0 || dif0d.Count > 0)
            {
                loopErrors.Add($"SetDifference.Novel !Sequence= LINQ");
            }

            // Reset state for next run
            disjoint.Clear();
            novel.Clear();

            // Add errors
            if (loopErrors.Any())
            {
                loopOps.AddRange(loopErrors);
                errors.Add(i, loopOps);
            }

            GC.Collect();

            // Print errors or performance comparison
            if (errors.Any())
            {
                foreach (var kv in errors)
                {
                    foreach (var item in kv.Value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var editedCount = loopOps.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Transform")).Count();
                var newedCount = loopOps.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Add")).Count();
                var removedCount = loopOps.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Remove")).Count();
                Console.WriteLine($"Size: {strings.Count, -10} Edit/New/Remove: ({editedCount}/{newedCount}/{removedCount})");
                Console.WriteLine($"SET/LINQ: {SET_round_ticks}/{LINQ_round_ticks}");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Totals SetDifferentiator/LINQ.Except()x2: {totalTimeSpent_Set_Ticks}/{totalTimeSpent_LINQ_Ticks}");

    }

    protected List<string> GetLongListOfStrings(int num)
    {
        num = Math.Max(1, num);

        var rnd = new Random();
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            for (int j = 1; j < rnd.Next(1, 10); j++)
            {
                str += Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            result.Add(str);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time reconciling your description/title and the actual code; it doesn't seem to do what I'd expect given the description. Can you show us the context you'd use this in and what information you need, and why?

Answer (score 5):

1) You should never use `this` in a `lock()` statement. Instead use `swapHashes` or create a dedicated `private object lockObject = new object();` and use it in the `lock()` statement:

```
lock (lockObject) {...}
```

---

2) When `GetDifference(...)` checks the input list it does not find changes to items in the list, if they are of reference types. In your test environment it find changes to the string items, because a string behaves like a value type in this case and the changes made to the string actually make a new string - not a change to the existing string object. So your method actually finds a new string not a changed string.

If your list was a list of a class like:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and you changed an item in the list like this:

```
list[index].Value = "New Value";
```

then it would not be found as a change.

If you're going to use the class with lists of reference types you need to track the state of each item between calls to `GetDifference(...)` - which could be a hash or something like that.

---

3) Have you considered using `ObservableCollection<T>` and let the item class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to keep track of collection and item changes in a dynamically and event driven way?

Comment: 1) Okay.  That was my original implementation.  If I do the lock to protect against multithreaded use I should do the lock correctly.  
2) This is a good point.  I wonder which way to go.  This has to operate in a highly performance critical application loop.  There is not the requirement that the set differentiator work on reference types directly.  To support this generic solution and work with reference objects it would have to work on T that implements an interface that has a function that returns TValue, which is the value-type property of the ref-type to operate on.

Comment: Last question - since this is a code review, typically I would modify the code and request updated feedback.  It doesn't seem like StackExchange has any kind of plugin that would make this process native to the UI.  So, what is the habit of users of this site?  To modify the original question?  That would seem to result in a bunch of commentary that doesn't make sense.  To make a new Question?  Add an answer and let people comment on that?  I'm confused how to elicit follow-on reviews of modified code.

Comment: 3) This is an interesting proposal.  My suspicion is that it couldn't possibly handle the performance requirements of the real module this is meant to fit into.  However, it is worth investigating, but it would likely necessitate changes to code downstream and that's all pretty complex and handled by another team.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @jeromeyers: The rule is, that it is not allowed to update the code after the question has been answered. Some answer their own question with an update, others make a new question for a new review. I think you can find more precise rules somwhere?